# No Interactions when dynamically adding items to flowbite accordion component

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, flowbite

So I am using Flowbite and vanilla JavaScript to do a UI.

I am dynamically adding items to an accordion by loading them (via PHP) from a DB. So the PHP script returns an id, section name and section text as JSON.

Now this script then generates the HTML to fit in the accordion container:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    fetch('src/php/getExecSummary.php')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        const accordionContainer = document.getElementById('accordionExecSummary');
        
        data.forEach((section, index) => {
            const isOpen = index === 0 ? true : false;
            const sectionElement = `
                <h2 id="accordion-heading-${index}">
                    <button type="button" data-accordion-target="#accordion-collapse-body-${index}" class="flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 font-medium text-left border-b border-gray-200" aria-expanded="${isOpen}" aria-controls="accordion-collapse-body-${index}">
                        <span>${section.SectionName}</span>
                        <!-- Include accordion icon here -->
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="accordion-collapse-body-${index}" class="${isOpen ? '' : 'hidden'}" aria-labelledby="accordion-heading-${index}">
                    <div class="p-5 border-b border-gray-200">
                        <textarea class="w-full h-32 p-2 border border-gray-300">${section.SectionText}</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;            
            accordionContainer.innerHTML += sectionElement;
        });

    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error loading executive summary sections:', error));
});
```

So I get the sections and the sections are named from data back from the DB but I cannot interact with the accordion; so clicking the section name doesn't expand/collapse the section. No errors in the console and cant find any `refresh()` method or anything like that.

Not sure what else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/accordion/#javascript-behaviour):

> #### JavaScript Behaviour
>
> Use the **Accordion** object from Flowbite to create a collection of vertically collapsing heading and content elements using object parameters, options, methods, and callback functions directly from JavaScript.

As per [the example](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/accordion/#example), we need to build the list of `items` that are the accordions within the accordion group. We can turn the `.forEach()` into a map like so:

```
const items = data.map((section, index) => {
  // …
  accordionContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', sectionElement);
        
  return {
    id: `accordion-collapse-body-${index}`,
    triggerEl: accordionContainer.querySelector(`#accordion-heading-${index} button`),
    targetEl: document.getElementById(`accordion-collapse-body-${index}`),
    active: isOpen,
  };
});
```

It is important to replace the `.innerHTML` assignment with the above `.insertAdjaccentHTML()` call. This is because `.innerHTML` assignment causes the entire inner HTML of the container to be reparsed, meaning that previous JavaScript object representations don't actually refer to their elements anymore, whereas `.insertAdjaccentHTML()` prevents this from happening.

After this, initialize a new `Accordion` object from Flowbite:

```js
new Accordion(accordionContainer, items);
```

Full example:

```js
const demoFetch = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(
    () => {
      resolve({
        json: () => Promise.resolve([
          {
            SectionName: 'Foo',
            SectionText: 'Foo content',
          },
          {
            SectionName: 'Bar',
            SectionText: 'Bar content',
          },
        ]),
      });
    },
    500,
  );
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  demoFetch('src/php/getExecSummary.php')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const accordionContainer = document.getElementById('accordionExecSummary');

      const items = data.map((section, index) => {
        const isOpen = index === 0 ? true : false;
        const sectionElement = `
          <h2 id="accordion-heading-${index}">
            <button type="button" data-accordion-target="#accordion-collapse-body-${index}" class="flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 font-medium text-left border-b border-gray-200" aria-expanded="${isOpen}" aria-controls="accordion-collapse-body-${index}">
              <span>${section.SectionName}</span>
              <!-- Include accordion icon here -->
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="accordion-collapse-body-${index}" class="${isOpen ? '' : 'hidden'}" aria-labelledby="accordion-heading-${index}">
            <div class="p-5 border-b border-gray-200">
              <textarea class="w-full h-32 p-2 border border-gray-300">${section.SectionText}</textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        `;
        accordionContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', sectionElement);
        
        return {
          id: `accordion-collapse-body-${index}`,
          triggerEl: accordionContainer.querySelector(`#accordion-heading-${index} button`),
          targetEl: document.getElementById(`accordion-collapse-body-${index}`),
          active: isOpen,
        };
      });

      new Accordion(accordionContainer, items);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error loading executive summary sections:', error));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.3.0/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.3.0/flowbite.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordionExecSummary"></div>
```